# Kotlinx cannot resolve symbol "synthetic"

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

Trying Kotlin, Kotlin configured in project, `kotlin-android-extensions`added, dependency also added...

```
import kotlinx.android.**synthetic**.main.content_main.*
```

[[image: ]]

Comment: can you add little more description?

Comment: You can't use the kotlin android extensions in Java. They are for Kotlin.

Comment: @AniruddhaDas All modules with Kotlin files are configured.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, of course, you got the error. You must change your code to Kotlin not java. Something likes:

```
class YourActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
}
```

And remember that, it's should be `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*` not `content_main`

Comment: I'm getting this same error in a Kotlin file just now, and not even `Invalidate Caches` fixes it. hrmmm

Comment: okay I had to force a Gradle Sync, pretty much. Updating kotlin gradle plugin fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {}
```

Change your class from Java to Kotlin so that it can import kotlin packages